# Neo4j - get friend list up to the 4th degree

Tags: codeigniter, neo4j

I am working with one application which requires to show a friend list up to the 4th degree. After some research I came to know about one solution i.e. Neo4j.

I didn't get a clear idea from their tutorial, can I connect Neo4j to MySQL, and if not how should I implement that myself? I am currently using the codeigniter framework with MySQL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

neo4j is a database, and mysql is a database.  so, this question is largely about connecting databases from different vendors together.

at this time, neo4j and mysql do not support direct connections to each other.  you'd typically accomplish your desired task by exporting your data from mysql as CSV files (http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-export-table-to-csv/) and importing to neo4j (http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/)

michael hunger, a colleague of mine at neo4j, recently wrote this auto importer.  you might want to check it out to make this process much easier:
https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-rdbms-import

before going through this data export/import, you may just want to download neo4j and play with the movie dataset.  you can do this in about a minute (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om6E-HqtrZ0).

then, there are standalone PHP drivers for Neo4j:
http://neo4j.com/developer/php/

josh addell, the author of Neo4jPHP, has even written a post about how to use codeignitor 2 with his library:
http://blog.everymansoftware.com/2011/08/getting-neo4jphp-working-with.html